# changing an button image of a tableview

Tags: swift

I have been trying to solve a problem, but cannot seem to find a solution.
I have a tableviewcell which contains a button. the button has an image set to it. I would like to change the image when the button is pressed, but I am lacking the proper code for this and where the code needs to be inserted (either in the code inside of tableviewcontoller or tableviewcell file).
I know that the normal code is: self.practicePlayButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play4.png"), forState: .Highlighted)
for changing the buttons... But I seem to be stumped here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.practicePlayButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play4.png"), forState: .Highlighted)
```

Replace this...

```
self.practicePlayButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play4.png"), forState: .Selected)
```

Comment: This completed answered my question.